# carousel is not responding on bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have build carousel for my clients which works perfect on non bootstrap platform but same thing i did on bootstrap to make it responsive it stop respond like was doing on non bootstrap platform. there is js issue which is not working properly.

Here is my code

```js
var $clientcarousel = $('#clients-list');
var clients = $clientcarousel.children().length;
var clientwidth = (clients * 140); // 140px width for each client item 
$clientcarousel.css('width', clientwidth);

var rotating = true;
var clientspeed = 1800;
var seeclients = setInterval(rotateClients, clientspeed);

$(document).on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    rotating = false; // turn off rotation when hovering
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    rotating = true;
  }
}, '#clients');

function rotateClients() {
  if (rotating != false) {
    var $first = $('#clients-list li:first');
    $first.animate({
      'margin-left': '-140px'
    }, 600, function() {
      $first.remove().css({
        'margin-left': '0px'
      });
      $('#clients-list li:last').after($first);
    });
  }
}
});
```

```css
#clients {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#clients .clients-wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#clients .clients-wrap ul {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

#clients .clients-wrap ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
}

#clients .clients-wrap ul li img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=65)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
  opacity: 0.65;
}

#clients .clients-wrap ul li img:hover {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="clients">
      <div class="clients-wrap">
        <ul id="clients-list" class="clearfix navbar">
          <li class="nav-item"><img class="nav-link img-fluid" src="_images/client01-cartoon-network.png" alt="Cartoon Network"></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><img class="nav-link img-fluid" src="_images/client02-rough-draft-studios.png" alt="Rough Draft Studios"></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><img class="nav-link img-fluid" src="_images/client03-spongebob-movie2.png" alt="SpongeBob Movie #2"></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><img class="nav-link img-fluid" src="_images/client04-apple-inc.png" alt="Apple Computers"></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><img class="nav-link img-fluid" src="_images/client05-google-talk.png" alt="Google chat talk"></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><img class="nav-link img-fluid" src="_images/client06-g4tv.png" alt="G4TV channel"></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><img class="nav-link img-fluid" src="_images/client07-wonka-candy.png" alt="Wonka Chocolates and Candy"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- @end .clients-wrap -->
    </div>
    <!-- @end #clients -->
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: can you create fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/59w7dvou/1/ 
here is it's fiddle it is not sliding one by one even not being in one row and being responsive as they should be.

Comment: can you check this https://jsfiddle.net/59w7dvou/1/

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/59w7dvou/5/

Comment: it is working perfect but now it lost it's responsiveness can you sort that out too. i cannot think what can be wrong there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated code:**

i included jquery `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js`

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">


      <div id="clients">
        <div class="clients-wrap">
          <ul id="clients-list" class="clearfix navbar">
            <li class="nav-item"><img class="nav-link img-fluid" src="http://i.imgur.com/sqOrTvo.png" alt="Cartoon Network"></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><img class="nav-link img-fluid" src="http://imgur.com/Eu0IboI.png" alt="Rough Draft Studios"></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><img class="nav-link img-fluid" src="http://imgur.com/n0RJ0p3.png" alt="SpongeBob Movie #2"></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><img class="nav-link img-fluid" src="http://imgur.com/VdV6cWz.png" alt="Apple Computers"></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><img class="nav-link img-fluid" src="http://imgur.com/VdV6cWz.png" alt="Google chat talk"></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><img class="nav-link img-fluid" src="http://imgur.com/udZvHOB.png" alt="G4TV channel"></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><img class="nav-link img-fluid" src="http://imgur.com/EehPfDN.png" alt="Wonka Chocolates and Candy"></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- @end .clients-wrap -->
      </div><!-- @end #clients -->
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>



<script>
    var $clientcarousel = $('#clients-list');
    var clients = $clientcarousel.children().length;
    var clientwidth = (clients * 140); // 140px width for each client item 
    $clientcarousel.css('width', clientwidth);

    var rotating = true;
    var clientspeed = 1800;
    var seeclients = setInterval(rotateClients, clientspeed);

    $(document).on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            rotating = false; // turn off rotation when hovering
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            rotating = true;
        }
    }, '#clients');

    function rotateClients() {
        if (rotating != false) {
            var $first = $('#clients-list li:first');
            $first.animate({
                'margin-left': '-140px'
            }, 600, function() {
                $first.remove().css({
                    'margin-left': '0px'
                });
                $('#clients-list li:last').after($first);
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

[updated fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/59w7dvou/9/)

Comment: what can now fix it's responsivenss now which is now in two lines instead just in one

Comment: glad to help you